# OpenSSL verification failing with CA signed cert but not with self signed one?

Tags: authentication, certificate, openssl

First of all, I know there are plenty of related questions but it seems like most of them are due to the lack of issuer certificates on the server.

I have been following [this guide](http://www.impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html) to enable client authentication with SSL, but I am stuck at getting Apache to accept the client certificate. Upon closer inspection, Apache logs are filled with `Certificate Verification: Error (20): unable to get local issuer certificate` messages.

I am using a certificate that a CA has given me and my private key as CA.

In order to further diagnose the issue, I ran `openssl verify -CAfile ca.cert client_signed.crt` and get the same error.

I decide to redo all steps. However, doing everything from the command line still returns the same error

```
$ openssl x509 -req -days 360 -in client.csr -CA ca.cert -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client_signed.crt
Signature ok
subject= ...
Getting CA Private Key
Enter pass phrase for server.key:
[I type in the password and press ENTER]
$ openssl verify -CAfile ca.cert client_signed.crt
[ .. ]
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
$ ls ca.cert
ca.cert
```

In order to fully diagnose the issue, I decide to generate and self sign a certificate to be used as CA in order to sign the client certificate. To my surprise, **this worked flawlessly**. This is actually the first step in the tutorial that I have linked.

So apparently, the issue is related to my certificate. I am suspecting there must be something related to the Chain of Trust since I don't have the certificate of the CA who signed my own certificate. I attempted to download them [from their website](http://www.correo.com.uy/index.asp?pagVal=211) but I can't even verify my own certificate.

```
$ ls /path/to/downloaded/files/
acrn.cer  ancca.crt  CorreoUruguayoCA.crt  CorreoUruguayoRootCA.crt
$ openssl verify -CApath /path/to/downloaded/files/ my.cert
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Using the "View File" utility on Ubuntu indicates that my certificate has been `Verified by: Correo Uruguayo - CA`. I am not sure why openssl is failing to verify it.